# main method not found in string program.please any one can help me out to execute the program without this error

Tags: java

```
public class String {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       java.lang.String s="Sachin";  
       s.concat(" Tendulkar");//concat() method appends the string at the end  
       System.out.println(s);//will print Sachin because strings are immutable objects  
    }  

}
```

can any one tell why I am getting this error in eclipse IDE

Comment: Rename your class, this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are using your own `String` class in the parameter type of the `main` method. You need to use `java.lang.String` there too:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args)
```

**Note:** It's better not to use the name of any class in the `java.lang` package for your own classes. This only leads to confusion...

Comment: And he should probably consider using a package without the com.java may trick someone to think it's official. And as you said rename to something like 'AppString'

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
public class String {
```

make shadows on the String class...
that is why you need to use the full name by doing

```
java.lang.String s="Sachin";
```

rename instead the class like

```
public class MyString {
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a solution